# Invalidate/Stop NSTimers associated with custom UITableViewCells when they go offscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nstimer

I have a customised `UITableViewCell` which makes use of a `NSTimer`. How do I stop or invalidate the timer when the screen pops.

I have tried

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is your timer not encapsulated into the cell directly? is there any particular reason not to do so?

Answer (score 1):

**You can stop timer for UITableviewCell using NSNotificationCenter**

**Step 1 in UITableViewCell file**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.stopTimer), name: "stopTimer", object: nil)
    }

func stopTimer(){
        if self.couponTimer != nil {
            self.couponTimer?.invalidate()
            self.couponTimer = nil
        }
    }
```

**Step 2 in ViewController file**

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("stopTimer", object: nil)
    }
```

Comment: This is often the best way.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things need to be in place for this to work:

1)

Have you set a delegate on your UITableView?

2)

Are you running for iOS 6 & newer?

If you set a breakpoint in "`didEndDisplayingCell:`", make certain you're invalidating the right timer.  And also set your custom cell's timer property or ivar to nil to be doubly sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably go with viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear, depending on when exactly you want the timer to stop. The first is probably your best bet. And let it Invalidate the timer(s), either directly or through a Notification.

And as Michael said in his answer, make sure to set the timer(s) to nil after you invalidate them.